# Extract time from JS Date object without offsetting the Time zone

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

So we have multiple clients, that are in multiple time zones. I'm pulling some dates from an API, and the dates/times that are in this string are exactly what I need to display. I've been researching this, and digging for some time, and still haven't come up with a clear answer. The string coming in is formatted as such:

```
"2017-12-29T20:00:00"
```

What I'm wanting is to extract both the date and time as is, into two strings (no timezone offsetting, no matter where the viewer is located) but am having some issues doing so. Also hoping to format it in the correct fashion as well. Example:

```
"M/d/yyyy"
"hh:mm AM/PM" (12 hour)
```

I've tried numerous ways to battle this, and don't really want to just grab substrings, but am half tempted to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using momentjs?  moment.format() would make this an easy task.  Otherwise I'd rather grab substrings than try to build it with the built in javascript getHour, getMinute, etc functions.

Comment: @cstricklan - If I had put this into moment.format(), would it automatically be offsetting any time zones? Or would it preserve the time/date that was supplied in the string?

Comment: the string `"2017-12-29T20:00:00"` contains no time zone information.  Yes, calling `moment("2017-12-29T20:00:00")` creates the moment object for 20:00 in your local timezone, but that's also the zone used by the format() function to create the string, so it would stay 10:00 PM.

Comment: Old advice still applies: **never use the built-in Date parser to parse strings**. Write your own function or use a library, there are plenty of good parsing and formatting libraries available (e.g. [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com), [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha)). Just treat the string as UTC and do all formatting using UTC methods to avoid any timezone issues. Alternatively, just reformat the string and avoid parsing issues altogether.

Comment: Just always use the UTC methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just reformatting the string, it avoids all issues with the built-in parser and timezones:

```js
function reformatTimestamp(s) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+ +n}
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var h = b[3]%12 || 12;
  var ap = b[3] < 12? 'AM':'PM';
  return b[1] + '/' + b[2] + '/' + b[0] +
         ' ' + z(h) + ':' + z(b[4]) + ' ' + ap;
}

console.log(reformatTimestamp('2017-12-29T20:00:00')) // 12/29/2017 08:00 PM
```

I think it would be better to pad the month and day with a leading zero (but I'd also use an unambiguous date format like DD-MMM-YYYY rather than the peculiar m/d/y).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getUTCHours();
  var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

var str = "2017-12-29T20:00:00";
var dt = new Date(str + "Z");
console.log("M/d/yyyy");
console.log((dt.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + dt.getUTCDate() + '/' +  dt.getUTCFullYear());
console.log("hh:mm AM/PM");
console.log(formatAMPM(dt));
```

Comment: @RobG yes you're right. I have deleted the options1 line accordingly :)